# How do I find the list of students in database in java using ajax?

Tags: javascript, java, mysql, json, ajax

I have a project that I use DAO/ajax/servlet/hibernate and mysql for it . I write a dynamic table with javascript that show result of every opration :delete,add,update,search
this is my code :

```
<table id="allStudent" class="table table-bordered">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>FirstName</th>
                    <th>LastName</th>
                    <th>studentCode</th>
                    <th>Major</th>
                    <th>FatherName</th>
                    <th>id</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="tmplBody">
                    <script id="scriptTmp">

                    <tr id="deleteTr" >

                        <td>
                            ${firstName}

                        <td>
                            ${lastName}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            ${studentCode}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            ${major}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            ${fatherName}
                        </td>
                         <td>
                            ${id}
                        </td>
                        <td>

                            <button id="updateStudent" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-pencil" style="padding-right: 10px;"></i>
                                Update
                            </button>

                            <a href="#" type="button"  class="btn btn-danger deletebtn" role="button" onclick="deleteSt(${id})"><i class="fa fa-trash" style="padding-right: 10px;"></i>
                                Delete
                            </a>
                            <button  class="btn btn-info" role="button"><i class="fa fa-check" style="padding-right: 10px;"></i>Course
                                Selection
                            </button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    </script>
                </tbody>


            </table>

        </div>
```

and in servlet I have findAll() to show all students . also I hava a ajax for it:

```
  protected void findAll(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
    ArrayList<Student> list = service.GetAll();
    json = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(list);
    out.print(json);
}
```

I don't know how I search students with everything that user inter in search box ....examples in internet use spring but i don't want use it now.help please

Comment: I hope I'm not the only one, but I do not understand your problem.

Comment: "_I use DAO/ajax/servlet/hibernate and mysql for it_" And what are you not able to use in those technologies ? "_I don't know how I search students with everything that user inter in search box_" You mean build the ajax request, extract the parameter from the request in the servlet or write the SQL query ? "_examples in internet use spring but i don't want use it now._" That's a good idea to start with the basics before trying to use complex framework!

Comment: @AxelH I want to if user write 1 or r or everything else ,every object that have this will show in table with javascript.

Comment: So you have a problem with `ajax`, the `dao` (which I guess is using `hibernate`), the `mysql` and also the `javascript` table to create after ? Could you at least try to specify what you can't do because from what I see, you can't do any of those step, which means you should follow tutorial on each technologies to be able to use the basics.